# Rails Routing with Unique User Identifiers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I create a user in my database, it also creates a unique identifier string.

In my routes, I have:

```
match '/users/:unique_identifer', :to => 'users#show'
```

This part is working fine. When I go to /users/xyz, it brings me to the show action for the appropriate user.

However, when I try to update the user record, it redirect me back to /users/SOMENUMBER where SOMENUMBER is the user's ID. This causes an error since the show action in the controller has:

```
def show
    @user = User.find_by_unique_identifier(params[:unique_identifer])
end
```

In other words, the show action is now only looking up the user by their unique identifier and not the user id.

The update action is as follows:

```
def update
    @user = User.find_by_unique_identifier(params[:unique_identifer])
    if @user == current_user && @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      redirect_to @user
    else
      redirect_to @user
    end
 end
```

How do I get the update action to redirect to the user's show action but with the appropriate link (/users/unique_identifier) instead of /users/ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
redirect_to user_path(@user.unique_identifer)
```

or

```
redirect_to :action => :show, :unique_identifer => @user.unique_identifer
```

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason it's not even getting to the point where it's calling the redirect_to actions from the update method. Could it have something to do with the routes or the fact that update_attributres is being called on params[:user]?

Comment: aha the isue might be in your edit form where you send the id instead the identifer

Comment: Yeah I think that is right. I currently have <%= form_for (@user) do %>, which is the problem. However, when I change it to <%= form_for (@user.unique_identifer) do %> it stil does not work. Any thoughts?

Comment: try `<%= form_for @user, :url => users_path(@user.unique_identifer) do %>` hope this send you automaticly PUT request if not add also :method => 'PUT'

Comment: Nice, I think that will work. There's only one small problem. The html for the form is putting action="/users.vi10fxvf" from that code you listed. Any idea what is going on there?

Comment: looks like it send the POST request try add the :method => 'PUT' to your form_for helper

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10898/discussion-between-alex-and-suborx)

Answer (score 2):

You should redefine to_param (and from_param to make life easier), it is used to generate links for objects, and by default use id field

so in your case

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    unique_identifer
  end
end
```

and now users_path(@user) should give you /users/your-uniq-identifier

here is nice description with examples:
http://apidock.com/rails/v3.1.0/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param

Comment: That is an interesting approach. I never thought of taking the route. Thanks!